# How to update sqlite3 from python?

Tags: centos, centos6, python, sqlite

How to update sqlite3 from python?

I am having problems with the old version of Slite3 for python3.6.

I need to upgrade for version 3.22.0 or last

```
root@server01# python3.6m
Python 3.6.7 (default, Dec  5 2018, 15:02:16)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-23)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version_info
(3, 6, 20)
>>> quit()
```

Comment: Stop using CentOS 6, upgrade to CentOS 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sqlite3` now comes in the [standard library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530974/how-can-i-install-sqlite3-to-python). You have to update your python. You could use a [virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv), if you want to preserve the System's python version.